# Алгоритм поиска свободных мест на автобус

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Есть вот такая структура таблиц в БД.

```
**flight**
-id
-bus_id 

**stations**
-id
-title

**flight_station**
-flight_id 
-station_id

**tickets**
-id
-flight_id
-fio
-price
-stationA_id (станция отправления)
-stationB_id (станция прибытия)
-place 
-date (дата и время отправления рейса)
-date_arrival (дата и время прибытия)
```

Мне нужно получить свободные места между станциими А и Б. Не могу понять саму логику реализации. Делаю все на Laravel.

Данные выглядят вот так:

```
<?php

/*
    Массив всех станций маршрута (1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9 - id станций). 
    Внутри массив уже занятых мест
        number - место
        stationA_id - станция отправления (по сути можно убрать, так как совпадает из ключем второго массива)
        stationB_id - станция прибытия 
*/

$stations_place = array ( 
    1 => array( 0 => array ( 'number' => '16', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                1 => array ( 'number' => '15', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ),
                2 => array ( 'number' => '14', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                3 => array ( 'number' => '13', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                4 => array ( 'number' => '2', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                5 => array ( 'number' => '11', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                6 => array ( 'number' => '3', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                7 => array ( 'number' => '4', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 6, ), 
                8 => array ( 'number' => '12', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                9 => array ( 'number' => '17', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                10 => array ( 'number' => '18', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                11 => array ( 'number' => '19', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
                12 => array ( 'number' => '20', 'stationA_id' => 1, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
    ), 
    2 => array ( 0 => array ( 'number' => '5', 'stationA_id' => 2, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
        1 => array ( 'number' => '6', 'stationA_id' => 2, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
        2 => array ( 'number' => '7', 'stationA_id' => 2, 'stationB_id' => 5, ), 
        3 => array ( 'number' => '8', 'stationA_id' => 2, 'stationB_id' => 9, ), 
    ), 
    3 => array ( ), 
    5 => array ( ), 
    6 => array ( ), 
    7 => array ( ), 
    8 => array ( ), 
    9 => array ( ), 
);

$total_place = 45; //Всего мест (вместимость автобуса);

$station_departure = 2; //id станции отправления
$station_arrival = 8; // id станции прибытия
$count_place = 1; //К-во нужных мест 


/*
    Вывести список свободных мест от Станции А ($station_departure) до Станции В ($station_arrival) кроме тех которые уже есть
    $stations_place. Также предусмотреть возможность что место может освободится на промежуточных станциях
Примечание:Структуру $stations_place можно изменить, если есть идеи.
*/

?>
```

Comment: Нужно взять список всех мест в автобусе и вычеркнуть из него те, которые заняты. Вопрос - а маршруты у вас есть? Может ли быть билет из В в Г, но при этом автобус едет В-А-Б-Г?

Comment: Как таковой таблици маршрутов нет. Название маршрута формируется по первой и последней станции. Может ли быть билет из В в Г - Да.

Comment: Список ВСЕХ занятых мест по данному маршруту у меня есть. Но как узнать что на станции Д до станции К оно уже будет свободным.

Comment: В лоб - получаете список всех станций искомого маршрута. Для каждой станции получаете список всех свободных мест. Теперь нужно просто перебрать все эти массивы и найти те места, которые есть в каждом.

Comment: Не до конца понял с перебором. К примеру у меня есть массив такого вида: $stations[$station_id] = array($number_places); Массив всех станций в качестве их значений массив мест откуда куплен билет. Что из чем тогда сравнивать ?

Comment: Делается так. Заполняется массив, где ключ - ID станции, значение - 0 в порядке следования станций на маршруте. Дальше цикл по всем заказам: в массиве для станции отправления делаем +1, для станции назначения -1. В итоге получаем массив с дельтами. Далее пробегаемся по всему массиву и добавляем к значению текущего значение предыдущего. Получаем заполненность транспорта для каждой остановки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие, у нас есть список билетов, которые куплены на каждой станции. Типа на станции №1 занято место №16 и едет человек со станции 1 до станции 9 и т.д. Если это так, то:

```
$free_places = []; //свободные места

for ($i=1; $i <= $total_place; $i++) {
   $free_places[] = 1; //заполняем единицами (пока все свободно)
}

if ($station_departure < $station_arrival) { //движемся в прямом направлении 1,2,3...

    foreach ($stations_place as $tickets) {
        foreach ($tickets as $ticket) { //перебираем билеты
            $from = $ticket['stationA_id'];
            $to = $ticket['stationB_id'];
            if ($from < $to) { //если билет в нашу сторону
                if ($station_arrival <= $from || $station_departure >= $to) {
                    //если нет пересечений, то нам эта поездка не мешает
                } else {
                    //в ином случае помечаем место как занятое
                    $free_places[ $ticket['number'] -1 ] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else { //едем в обратную сторону 9,8,7,6..
    foreach ($stations_place as $tickets) {
        foreach ($tickets as $ticket) { //перебираем билеты
            $from = $ticket['stationA_id'];
            $to = $ticket['stationB_id'];
            if ($from > $to) { //если билет в нашу ОБРАТНУЮ сторону
                if ($station_arrival >= $from || $station_departure <= $to) {
                    //если нет пересечений (все знаки наоборот)
                } else {
                    $free_places[ $ticket['number'] -1 ] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе `$free_places` будет содержать `1` в свободных местах и `0` в занятых. Дальше с этим массивом можно делать что угодно.

Comment: Второй цикл for //для всех станций с А по Б
Порядок станций может быть на оборот  9,8,7,6,5,4,3. Значить массив $stations_place так не перебрать.

Comment: @depredator поправил с учетом движения в обе стороны и того факта, что место могло быть занято до станции отправления и успеть освободиться тоже до или на ней.

Comment: Да, то что нужно. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

хм я думаю тут все просто

1. у нас есть места в автобусе с 1 по 45
2. У нас есть купленные билеты приуроченные к определенному времени с
   отмеченными местами

**Решение:**

```
<?php

interface IBus
{
    public function __construct(int $bus_id, DataKeeper $data, int $count_place);
    /**
     * Показывает id точек маршрута за конкретный день
     * 
     * @param string $date
     * @return array
     */ 
    public function getWayPoints(string $date );
    /**
     * получить свободные места автобуса в день  $date на остановке с id = $way_point_id
     * 
     * @param string $date
     * @param $way_point_id
     */ 
    public function getFreePlace(string $date,int $way_point_id);
}
/** 
 * класс по получению данных из внешних ресурсов
 */ 
class DataKeeper
{
    /**
     * Показывает id точек маршрута за конкретный день
     * 
     * @param string $date
     * @return array
     */ 
    public function getWayPointsByDay(string $date,int $bus_id): array
    {
        $time = strtotime($date);
        if ($time === flase){
            throw new \Exception('некорректно указана дата '.$date);
        }
        $date_start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $time);
        $date_end = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $time);
        $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `stationA_id` 
           FROM `tickets` 
           WHERE `flight_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `flight` WHERE `bus_id`='.((int)$bus_id).')
           AND `date`>"'.$date_start.'" AND `date`<"'.$date_end.'"';
        //TODO
        return [5,7,8];
    }
    /**
     * вытаскивает из базы все купленные места для дня $date, автобуса $bus_id на станции $point_id
     * 
     * @param string $date
     * @param int $point_id
     * @param int $bus_id
     * @return array
     */ 
    public function getBuyPlaces(string $date,int $point_id, int $bus_id):array
    {
        $time = strtotime($date);
        if ($time === flase){
            throw new \Exception('некорректно указана дата '.$date);
        }
        $date_start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $time);
        $date_end = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $time);
        $point_id = (int) $point_id;
        $bus_id = (int) $bus_id;
        $result = [];
        $sql='SELECT `place` 
            FROM `tickets`
            WHERE `flight_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `flight` WHERE `bus_id`='.((int)$bus_id).')
            AND `stationA_id` = '.$point_id.'
            AND `date`>"'.$date_start.'" AND `date`<"'.$date_end.'"';
        //TODO
        return $result;
    }
    /**
     * вытаскивает из базы все освободившиеся места места 
     * для дня $date, автобуса $bus_id на станции $point_id
     * 
     * @param string $date
     * @param int $point_id
     * @param int $bus_id
     * @return array
     */ 
    public function getEmptyPlaces(string $date,int $point_id, int $bus_id):array
    {
        $time = strtotime($date);
        if ($time === flase){
            throw new \Exception('некорректно указана дата '.$date);
        }
        $date_start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $time);
        $date_end = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $time);
        $point_id = (int) $point_id;
        $bus_id = (int) $bus_id;
        $result = [];
        $sql='SELECT `place` 
            FROM `tickets`
            WHERE `flight_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `flight` WHERE `bus_id`='.((int)$bus_id).')
            AND `stationB_id` = '.$point_id.'
            AND `date`>"'.$date_start.'" AND `date`<"'.$date_end.'"';
        //TODO
        return $result;
    }
}
/**
 * конкретный автобус
 */
class Bus implements IBus
{
    protected $bus_id = 0;
    /**
     * id точек маршрута приуроченные к конкретному дню и отсортированные по времени
     * к точкам маршрутов приписан массив с номерами занятых мест
     * ['2019-01-01'=>[2=>[],10=>[],20=>[],15=>[]]
     * 
     * @var $way_points
     */ 
    protected $way_points = [];
    protected $data_keeper;
    /**
     * количество мест в автобусе
     * 
     * @var $all_place
     */ 
    protected $count_place;
    public function __construct(int $bus_id, DataKeeper $data, int $count_place){
        $this->bus_id=$bus_id;
        $this->data_keeper = $data;
        $this->count_place = $count_place;
    }
    /**
     * Показывает id точек маршрута за конкретный день
     * 
     * @param string $date
     * @return array
     */ 
    public function getWayPoints(string $date ): array
    {
        $time = strtotime($date);
        if ($time === flase){
            throw new \Exception('некорректно указана дата '.$date);
        }
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
        if (!isset($this->way_points[$date])){
            $this->way_points[$date] = $this->data_keeper->getWayPointsByDay($date, $this->bus_id);
        }
        return $this->way_points[$date];
    }
    /**
     * получить свободные места автобуса в день  $date на остановке с id = $way_point_id
     * 
     * @param string $date
     * @param $way_point_id
     */ 
    public function getFreePlace(string $date,int $way_point_id):array
    {
        $time = strtotime($date);
        if ($time === flase){
            throw new \Exception('некорректно указана дата '.$date);
        }
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
        $way_point_id = (int) $way_point_id;
        $way_points = $this->getWayPoints($date);
        if(!in_array($way_point_id, $way_points)){
            throw new \Exception('в этот день автобус с id = '.$this->id
            .' не посещал остановку с id = '.$way_point_id);
        }
        if (!isset($this->$way_points[$date]['$way_point_id'])){
            $this->setBuyPlaces($date);
        }
        return $this->calculateFreePlaces($this->$way_points[$date]['$way_point_id']);
    }
    /**
     * выставляет занятые места с привязкой к каждой станции
     * место считается занятым, если пассажир,купивший это место, не выходит на этой станции
     * 
     * @param string $date
     */
    protected function setBuyPlaces(string $date):void
    {
        $time = strtotime($date);
        if ($time === flase){
            throw new \Exception('некорректно указана дата '.$date);
        }
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
        $occupied_places = []; //массив занятых мест
        foreach($this->getWayPoints($date ) as $point){
            $occupied_places = array_diff(
                $occupied_places
                ,$this->data_keeper->getEmptyPlaces($date,$point,$this->bus_id)
            );
            $occupied_places = array_merge(
                $occupied_places,
                $this->data_keeper->getBuyPlaces($date,$point,$this->bus_id)
            );
            $this->way_points[$date][$point] = $occupied_places;
        }
    }
    /**
     * высчитывает все свободные места автобуса исходя из имеющихся занятых мест и всего мест в автобусе
     *
     * @param array $buy_places
     */
    protected function calculateFreePlaces(array $buy_places): array
    {
        $result = [];
        for($i=1,$size_i=sizeof($this->count_place+1);$i<$size_i;$i++){
            if (!in_array($i,$buy_places)){
               $result[] =  $i;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }       
}

//как использовать
//есть автобусы c id

$bus_array = [24,56,10];
$data = new DataKeeper();
foreach($bus_array as $bus_id=>$bus){
    $bus_array[$bus_id] = new Bus($bus,$data,45);
}

//получить массив свободных мест всех автобусов на остановке с id 5 сегодня

$result = [];
foreach($bus_array as $bus_id=>$bus){
    $result[$bus_id] = $bus->getFreePlace(date('Y-m-d'),5);
}
print_r($result);
```

Здесь принято что:

- табличка с маршрутом в автобусе за весь день не меняется
- автобус делает 1 рейс в сутки по своему маршруту

если нужно будет расширить и эти условия - то можно будет отнаследоваться от класса Bus и расширить его функционал, также класс Bus позволяет создать метод расчета стоимости всех купленных билетов за день и даже пройденный километраж - если известно расстояние между точками.

Удачи. Если что не понятно - пишите. Скрипт делал для PHP 7.2

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Если бы только начинал делать,взял бы Ваш код за основу, но уже реализовано немного по другому и мне нужно просто было все вывести. Жаль что один ответ только можно признать правильным.